# Is it possible to consolidate mongodb primaries to a single secondary?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I want to achieve a configuration in which there are 3 primary mongodbs on 3 different servers and 1 mongodb running in the cloud. All the 3 primaries will have different collection names in which they write their data. What I want to achieve is that all the 3 primaries should sync their data to the one present in the cloud to their own collections. Is this possible? If yes, then can you point me to any resource for it? If no, then I think, I will have to have a seperate secondary in the cloud for each primary, right? 
I did quite extensive searches and went through mongodb docs but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If you can write your comment as an answer, I would be happy to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One mongodb process can't belong to more than one replica set, so you'll have to have three processes for the secondaries, be it on the same cloud server or several.